# Transaction Propagation in SSIS Packages

Tags: transactions, ssis

Following are the list of tasks performed by control flow in the SSIS package

1. Delete Data from table using "Execute SQL Task"
2. Read data from txt file and load data to table using "Data Flow Task"
3. Delete some rows from table (based on business logic) using "Execute SQL Task"
4. Update some rows in table (based on business logic) using "Execute SQL Task"

My doubt is, if there is an error in step 4, will SSIS automatically rollback to the state before step 1?

Can anyone help me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, each task is atomic. Task 4 will or will not complete, no half-measures will happen. If you need the package to succeed/fail as a whole, then you will need to configure it as such.

The easiest option is to use the built in transaction option for packages. This uses the Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) to handle transactions across various servers. In your package, right click on the background of your Control Flow and change the TransactionOption from `Supported` to `Required` More detail about how all that works over on
[How do I run multiple data flow tasks in parallel within the same transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369943/how-do-i-run-multiple-data-flow-tasks-in-parallel-within-the-same-transaction/10374998#10374998)

If MSDTC doesn't work for you for whatever reason, then you would need to either set the connection manager to RetainSameConnection and add a begin tran/commit/rollback logic into your package See [SSIS: Default Logging OnError don't work with RetainSameConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454062/ssis-default-logging-onerror-dont-work-with-retainsameconnection/11458177#11458177) for an example but that will *only* work if all the tasks are performed in the same database.

If MSDTC doesn't work and you will be modifying data in more than one database, then you'll need to write your own "rollback" scripts and have them fire in the OnError/OnTaskFailed events or the Error branch in your control flow. As you are issuing updates and deletes, that will require a change data capture mechanism be implemented prior to you being able to undo those operations.