# SQL JOB steps dependency

Tags: ssis

Let us say the sql job having 3 steps and each step executing a different ssis package.When the third step fails, How the SQl JOB rollback/delete the step1,step2 ssis packages inserts? Thanks for your reply in advance

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that is doable. As far as I know, session / transactions doesn't persist across packages.

If you're not constraint to a redesign, you may consider the following.

Preferably by merging all 3 packages into 1 and manage the transactions from there.

You should be able to find answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725353/transaction-propagation-in-ssis-packages) about propagating transactions between multiple task in SSIS package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Samuel.